# Dynamic WHERE clause in SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql, sql-server, dynamic-sql

I have a table which I'm querying using a dynamic conditional `WHERE` clause. I'm looking a best approach to get simple `WHERE` condition when all columns are null or when some columns has some value.

I tried something like this:

```
SET @CONDITIONS = CASE 
    WHEN @VEHICLE_TYPE_NAME IS NULL
        THEN '  ISNULL(A.VEHICLE_TYPE_NAME,'''') = ISNULL(A.VEHICLE_TYPE_NAME,'''') '
    ELSE '  A.VEHICLE_TYPE_NAME = ''' + @VEHICLE_TYPE_NAME + ''''
    END + ' ' + CASE 
    WHEN CAST(@PRODUCT_ID AS VARCHAR(MAX)) IS NULL
        THEN ' AND ISNULL(A.PRODUCT_ID, ''-1'') = ISNULL(A.PRODUCT_ID, ''-1'') '
    ELSE ' AND  A.PRODUCT_ID =  ''' + CAST(@PRODUCT_ID AS VARCHAR(MAX)) + ''''
    END + ' ' + CASE 
    WHEN CAST(@CAPABILITY_ID AS VARCHAR(MAX)) IS NULL
        THEN ' AND  ISNULL(A.CAPABILITY_ID,''-1'') = ISNULL(A.CAPABILITY_ID,''-1'') '
    ELSE ' AND  A.CAPABILITY_ID = ''' + CAST(@CAPABILITY_ID AS VARCHAR(MAX)) + ''''
    END + ' ' + CASE 
    WHEN @SPONSOR_FIRM_ID IS NULL
        THEN ' AND  ISNULL(A.SPONSOR_FIRM_ID,'''') = ISNULL(A.SPONSOR_FIRM_ID,'''') '
    ELSE ' AND  A.SPONSOR_FIRM_ID = ''' + @SPONSOR_FIRM_ID + ''''
    END + ' ' + CASE 
    WHEN @CLIENT_FIRM_ID IS NULL
        THEN ' AND  ISNULL(A.CLIENT_FIRM_ID,'''') =  ISNULL(A.CLIENT_FIRM_ID,'''')  '
    ELSE ' AND  A.CLIENT_FIRM_ID = ''' + @CLIENT_FIRM_ID + ''''
    END + ' ' + CASE 
    WHEN CAST(@DIST_PLATFORM_ID AS VARCHAR(MAX)) IS NULL
    THEN ' AND ISNULL(A.DIST_PLATFORM_ID,''-1'') = ISNULL(A.DIST_PLATFORM_ID,''-1'') '
    ELSE ' AND  A.DIST_PLATFORM_ID = ''' + CAST(@DIST_PLATFORM_ID AS VARCHAR(MAX)) + ''''
    END + ' ' + CASE 
    WHEN @RR_INTERNAL_NUMBER IS NULL
        THEN 'AND ISNULL(A.RR_INTERNAL_NUMBER,'''') =  ISNULL(A.RR_INTERNAL_NUMBER,'''') '
    ELSE ' AND  A.RR_INTERNAL_NUMBER = ''' + @RR_INTERNAL_NUMBER + ''''
    END
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the part where your parameter is null. You can simply build up a dynamic SQL for each part

```
IF @PRODUCT_ID IS NOT NULL
   @CONDITIONS = @CONDITIONS + ' AND  A.PRODUCT_ID =  ''' + CAST(@PRODUCT_ID AS VARCHAR(MAX)) + ''''
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need dynamic SQL?

```
WHERE (@VEHICLE_TYPE_NAME IS NULL OR A.VEHICLE_TYPE_NAME = @VEHICLE_TYPE_NAME)
      AND (@PRODUCT_ID IS NULL OR A.PRODUCT_ID = @PRODUCT_ID)
      ...
```

Comment: Im writing a sp to get all columns which are based on above condition and then displaying all these columns with total rows and order by based on columns which are using in sorting from UI. all the things like conditions , sorting columns and total rows counts comes with the help of dynamic SQL. any new approaches will appreciate